# How to projection fields for a dictionary (C#, MongdoDB)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying my luck here, I have a model which is like the following

```
public class RowData : BaseBsonDefinition
{
.
  [BsonExtraElements]
  [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)]
  public Dictionary<string, object> Rows { get; set; } = new(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
.
}
```

In result, the schema in the MongoDB looks like

```
{
"_id": {
    "$binary": {
      "base64": "HiuI1sgyT0OZmcgGUit2dw==",
      "subType": "03"
    }
  },
  "c1": "AAA",
  "c8": "Fully Vac",
  "c10": "",
}
```

Those c1, c8 and c10 fields are keys from the dictionary, my question is how to dynamic project those fields?

I tried

```
Builders<RowData>.Projection.Exclude(p => "c1")
```

It seems the MongoDB driver can not handle a value directly.

Anyone could point me in the correct direction?

Thanks,

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want to include or exclude these fields? If you want to exclude them, just use: `{$project: {_id: 1}}`

Comment: I want to exclude those fields based on different scenarios. For example in one situation I want to exclude C1 and sometime I want to exclude C1 and C2 so on and so forth. I need to use MongoDb driver, not really keen to call raw Mongo query directly.

Answer (score 1):

you can use follow code instead

```
Builders<RowData>.Projection.Exclude("c1");
```